# Integrating only over positive values of an oscillating function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have the following oscillatory function of time (it looks too lengthy!)

```
    myfun[t_] = 
  1/Log[2] (-((-E^(-0.001` t) (0.001` Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] - 
              0.09999499987499376` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]) + 
           0.001` E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
              0.010000500037503125` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]))/(1 -
            E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
              0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                0.09999499987499376` t]))^2) + ((1 - 
            E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
               0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                 0.09999499987499376` t])) (E^(-0.002` t) (0.001` Cos[
                 0.09999499987499376` t] - 
               0.09999499987499376` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]) (Cos[
                0.09999499987499376` t] + 
               0.010000500037503125` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]) - 
            0.001` E^(-0.002` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
               0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                 0.09999499987499376` t])^2) + (-E^(-0.001` t) \
(0.001` Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] - 
               0.09999499987499376` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]) + 
            0.001` E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
               0.010000500037503125` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t])) (1/
            2 + 
            1/2 E^(-0.002` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
               0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                 0.09999499987499376` t])^2))/(2 (1 - 
           E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
              0.010000500037503125` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]))^(
         3/2) \[Sqrt]((1 - 
              E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                 0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                   0.09999499987499376` t])) (1/2 + 
              1/2 E^(-0.002` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                 0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                   0.09999499987499376` t])^2))) - (3 (-E^(-0.001` t) \
(0.001` Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] - 
              0.09999499987499376` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]) + 
           0.001` E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
              0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                0.09999499987499376` t])) \[Sqrt]((1 - 
              E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                 0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                   0.09999499987499376` t])) (1/2 + 
              1/2 E^(-0.002` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                 0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                   0.09999499987499376` t])^2)))/(2 (1 - 
           E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
              0.010000500037503125` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]))^(
         5/2))) + 
   1/Log[2] Log[
      1/(1 - E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
           0.010000500037503125` Sin[
             0.09999499987499376` t])) + (\[Sqrt]((1 - 
              E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                 0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                   0.09999499987499376` t])) (1/2 + 
              1/2 E^(-0.002` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                 0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                   0.09999499987499376` t])^2)))/(1 - 
          E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
             0.010000500037503125` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]))^(
        3/2)] (-((-E^(-0.001` t) (0.001` Cos[
                 0.09999499987499376` t] - 
               0.09999499987499376` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]) + 
            0.001` E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
               0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                 0.09999499987499376` t]))/(1 - 
            E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
               0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                 0.09999499987499376` t]))^2) + ((1 - 
             E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                0.010000500037503125` Sin[

                  0.09999499987499376` t])) (E^(-0.002` t) (0.001` \
Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] - 
                0.09999499987499376` Sin[
                  0.09999499987499376` t]) (Cos[
                 0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                0.010000500037503125` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]) - 
             0.001` E^(-0.002` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                  0.09999499987499376` t])^2) + (-E^(-0.001` t) \
(0.001` Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] - 
                0.09999499987499376` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]) + 
             0.001` E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                  0.09999499987499376` t])) (1/2 + 
             1/2 E^(-0.002` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                  0.09999499987499376` t])^2))/(2 (1 - 
            E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
               0.010000500037503125` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]))^(
          3/2) \[Sqrt]((1 - 
               E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                  0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                    0.09999499987499376` t])) (1/2 + 
               1/2 E^(-0.002` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 

                  0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                    0.09999499987499376` t])^2))) - (3 (-E^(-0.001` \
t) (0.001` Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] - 
               0.09999499987499376` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]) + 
            0.001` E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
               0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                 0.09999499987499376` t])) \[Sqrt]((1 - 
               E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                  0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                    0.09999499987499376` t])) (1/2 + 
               1/2 E^(-0.002` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                  0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                    0.09999499987499376` t])^2)))/(2 (1 - 
            E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
               0.010000500037503125` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]))^(
          5/2))) + 
   1/Log[2] (-((-E^(-0.001` t) (0.001` Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] - 
              0.09999499987499376` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]) + 
           0.001` E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
              0.010000500037503125` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]))/(1 -
            E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
              0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                0.09999499987499376` t]))^2) - ((1 - 
            E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
               0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                 0.09999499987499376` t])) (E^(-0.002` t) (0.001` Cos[
                 0.09999499987499376` t] - 
               0.09999499987499376` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]) (Cos[
                0.09999499987499376` t] + 
               0.010000500037503125` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]) - 
            0.001` E^(-0.002` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
               0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                 0.09999499987499376` t])^2) + (-E^(-0.001` t) \
(0.001` Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] - 
               0.09999499987499376` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]) + 
            0.001` E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
               0.010000500037503125` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t])) (1/
            2 + 1/2 E^(-0.002` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
               0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                 0.09999499987499376` t])^2))/(2 (1 - 
           E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
              0.010000500037503125` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]))^(
         3/2) \[Sqrt]((1 - 
              E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 

                 0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                   0.09999499987499376` t])) (1/2 + 
              1/2 E^(-0.002` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                 0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                   0.09999499987499376` t])^2))) + (3 (-E^(-0.001` t) \
(0.001` Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] - 
              0.09999499987499376` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]) + 
           0.001` E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
              0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                0.09999499987499376` t])) \[Sqrt]((1 - 
              E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                 0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                   0.09999499987499376` t])) (1/2 + 
              1/2 E^(-0.002` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                 0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                   0.09999499987499376` t])^2)))/(2 (1 - 
           E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
              0.010000500037503125` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]))^(
         5/2))) + 
   1/Log[2] Log[
      1/(1 - E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
           0.010000500037503125` Sin[
             0.09999499987499376` t])) - (\[Sqrt]((1 - 
              E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 

                 0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                   0.09999499987499376` t])) (1/2 + 
              1/2 E^(-0.002` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                 0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                   0.09999499987499376` t])^2)))/(1 - 
          E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
             0.010000500037503125` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]))^(
        3/2)] (-((-E^(-0.001` t) (0.001` Cos[
                 0.09999499987499376` t] - 
               0.09999499987499376` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]) + 
            0.001` E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
               0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                 0.09999499987499376` t]))/(1 - 
            E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
               0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                 0.09999499987499376` t]))^2) - ((1 - 
             E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                  0.09999499987499376` t])) (E^(-0.002` t) (0.001` \
Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] - 
                0.09999499987499376` Sin[
                  0.09999499987499376` t]) (Cos[
                 0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                0.010000500037503125` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]) - 
             0.001` E^(-0.002` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 

                0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                  0.09999499987499376` t])^2) + (-E^(-0.001` t) \
(0.001` Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] - 
                0.09999499987499376` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]) + 
             0.001` E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                  0.09999499987499376` t])) (1/2 + 
             1/2 E^(-0.002` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                  0.09999499987499376` t])^2))/(2 (1 - 
            E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
               0.010000500037503125` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]))^(
          3/2) \[Sqrt]((1 - 
               E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                  0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                    0.09999499987499376` t])) (1/2 + 
               1/2 E^(-0.002` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                  0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                    0.09999499987499376` t])^2))) + (3 (-E^(-0.001` \
t) (0.001` Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] - 
               0.09999499987499376` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]) + 
            0.001` E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
               0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                 0.09999499987499376` t])) \[Sqrt]((1 - 
               E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                  0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                    0.09999499987499376` t])) (1/2 + 
               1/2 E^(-0.002` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
                  0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                    0.09999499987499376` t])^2)))/(2 (1 - 
            E^(-0.001` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
               0.010000500037503125` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]))^(
          5/2))) + (Log[
       1/2 - 1/2 Sqrt[
         1/2 + 1/2 E^(-0.002` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
             0.010000500037503125` Sin[
               0.09999499987499376` t])^2]] (E^(-0.002` t) (0.001` \
Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] - 
           0.09999499987499376` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]) (Cos[
            0.09999499987499376` t] + 
           0.010000500037503125` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]) - 
        0.001` E^(-0.002` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
           0.010000500037503125` Sin[
             0.09999499987499376` t])^2))/(4 Log[2] Sqrt[
      1/2 + 1/2 E^(-0.002` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
          0.010000500037503125` Sin[
            0.09999499987499376` t])^2]) - (Log[
       1/2 (1 + Sqrt[
          1/2 + 1/2 E^(-0.002` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
              0.010000500037503125` Sin[
                0.09999499987499376` t])^2])] (E^(-0.002` t) (0.001` \
Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] - 
           0.09999499987499376` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]) (Cos[
            0.09999499987499376` t] + 
           0.010000500037503125` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t]) - 
        0.001` E^(-0.002` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
           0.010000500037503125` Sin[
             0.09999499987499376` t])^2))/(4 Log[2] Sqrt[
      1/2 + 1/2 E^(-0.002` t) (Cos[0.09999499987499376` t] + 
          0.010000500037503125` Sin[0.09999499987499376` t])^2]);
```

This function gives an oscillating curve. I want to integrate only over those time intervals for which curve is positive. How can this be achieved using Mathematica?

Edit: I stand corrected. I want to integrate over the time intervals for which `myfun` is positive (not its slope).

Comment: "over the time intervals for which `myfun` is positive" - then just use `Clip[]` or `Max[]`

Comment: Could you kindly explain it as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

As J.M. says, clip the function to positive values:

```
Plot[Clip[myfun[t], {0, ∞}], {t, 0, 200}]
```

Then you can integrate it using `Integrate` or `NIntegrate`:

```
NIntegrate[Clip[myfun[t], {0, ∞}], {t, 0, 200}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
```

> 266.413

Alternatively, you can notice that the positive intervals are $[T,2T]$, $[3T,4T]$, $[5T,6T]$ etc. with $T=π/0.09999499987499376$. Thus the integral over the $i^{\text{th}}$ positive interval is

```
posint[i_Integer /; i >= 1] := 
  With[{T = π/0.09999499987499376}, 
    NIntegrate[myfun[t], {t, (2 i - 1) T, (2 i) T}]]
```

The above result is confirmed with

```
Sum[posint[i], {i, 3}]
```

> 266.413

Comment: Thanks, @Roman. I want the integral as a curve/plot (indefinite integral). Can it be done?

Comment: Your formula looks too complex for an analytic integration.